# HTML code won't load correctly using Django or Flask

Tags: html, django

Using the exact steps listed here,
https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/

and separately following tutorials for flask, I am able to run websites but the website itself always includes extra html codes, instead of simply "Hello, World!"

On the website it says:

```
<!doctype html>
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

Why?

I am saving my html file in a template folder.
Using Django what is "translating the below"? Is it render?

hello_world.html

```
<!doctype html>
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

I tried moving from flask to Django but same problem occurs.

Comment: What is the exact difference between the template and the generated HTTP response?

Comment: the website says : <!doctype html>
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>             I need it to say Hello, World!

Comment: can you add error to your post ?

Comment: The error is up there. All the html code shows up instead of displaying Hello World! 

I want 14 characters to show up, but instead I get all the html coding.